# Replace Function on VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have this code,

```
Dim str As String, Dim replaceStr As String, Dim counter as Integer
str = "I have the number 3"

For counter = 1 To 5
    replaceStr = Replace(str, counter, 99)
Next counter
```

I want the replace function to catch when the `counter = 3` so that it replaces the 3 with 99. 
So far I am still getting `"I have the number 3"`.

I have tried `Replace(str, CStr(counter), 99)` and still gives me the same results.

Comment: Having those 3 `Dim` on the first line is a syntax error

Comment: If you check the value of `replaceStr` AFTER the for loop completes you will have `I have the number 3` because the LAST iteration of the FOR loop was number "5". Instead, toss `debug.print replaceStr` INSIDE your FOR loop and rerun. You'll see 5 lines printed to your immediate pane and the third will properly read `I have the number 99` as you expect.

Answer (score 4):

You are doing the replacement when counter equals 3 but then undoing the replacement in the next pass through the loop. If you change your code to:

```
Sub test()
Dim str As String, replaceStr As String, counter As Integer
str = "I have the number 3"

For counter = 1 To 5
    replaceStr = Replace(str, counter, 99)
    Debug.Print replaceStr
Next counter
End Sub
```

You will see the output:

```
I have the number 3
I have the number 3
I have the number 99
I have the number 3
I have the number 3
```

Perhaps you can add the line `If replaceStr <> str Then Exit For` immediately after the `Replace`

Comment: And to you for a far better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the change to the actual string and not keep bringing in a "fresh" str.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
    Dim str As String, replaceStr As String, counter As Long

    str = "I have the number 3"

    For counter = 1 To 5
           str = Replace(str, counter, 99)
    Next counter

    Debug.Print str
End Sub
```

Comment: This would work for OP's stated problem but might behave unexpectedly if `For counter = 1 To 5` were changed to e.g. `For counter = 1 To 9`

Comment: @JohnColeman Very true. I have swopped it for directly applying change to the str variable.

Comment: Although, this might not be what is wanted!

Comment: But maybe it is (so +1) -- one purpose of Stack Overflow is to give ideas which can help programmers, not to give them complete solutions.